# Easy way to create a Google Form with a lot of images?

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to create an online survey with multiple images, where each participant would write what they call the thing depicted.

Each question would be composed of an image and a textbox for the answer.

I've started doing it in Google Forms, but it's very tedious. Is there a way to automate the Forms' creation ?

(If it's possible in a tool other than Forms, I'm open to suggestions).

Comment: Is Google Apps Script and option for you?  It is JavaScript based and allows the ability to either create your own HTML form "web app" or create a Google Form with calls such as [addImageItem().](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addImageItem())

Comment: @Karl_S I think this will work just fine, thanks! Write it as an answer if you want the bounty :)

Comment: No need, @Manu Hold onto the points for yourself.  I only offered a suggestion which meant a week's worth of work.  :)

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user seven times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a really easy built-in way to create a Google Form with multiple images but you could use Google Apps Script or a third-party app that uses it.

If you go by using Google Apps Script, you should use the Form Service (`FormApp`), more specifically [FormApp.create(title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#create(String)) to create a new form, [addImageItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addimageitem) to add an item image. Unfortunately Google Apps Script doesn't allow to add images to multiple choice items.

The third-party apps that might help with this could listed in the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace), most probable as a Google Form or Google Sheets add-on.

Related

- [Cannot add image from Google Drive to a Google Form using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37182861/1595451)
- [Insert image in multiplechoiceitem in Google Forms with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51427821/1595451)
- [How to get image inside a form item in google apps scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67480686/1595451)